# Detecting earphone button press

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-voip

I am developing a VOIP app based on the [VoipChatterbox](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ChatterBox-VoIP-sample-app-b1e63b8b) sample app project and I need to manipulate the headset button click.

I see that, during an active call, when I press the button on the earphone, I get a [CallEndRequested](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.phone.networking.voip.voipphonecall.endrequested.aspx) event and I need to call NotifyCallEnded within 5 seconds.

But I need a different behavior for my app. I need to simply turn the microphone off / on (toggle behavior) when the user presses the headset button. (This requirement might seem odd, but that's what make sense in the context of my application). How can I achieve this behavior?

To summarize :

Is there any other event to understand that user has pressed the earphone button?
Is there a way to override the behavior that NotifyCallEnded should be called in five seconds when [CallEndRequested](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.phone.networking.voip.voipphonecall.endrequested.aspx) event is fired?